# Select date in datapicker with calabach

Tags: android, ruby, cucumber, calabash

In Calabash Automation testing on Android. I need to select a date from a date picker. Please guide me with a ruby step definition.

I want something like

Then I scroll datepicker to date "20-05-2017"

Answer (score 0):

According to calabash-android GitHub repository, you can use these calabash canned-steps:

https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/ruby-gem/lib/calabash-android/steps/date_picker_steps.rb